# Retrieve My Documents After Being Removed From Domain

Tags: windows-xp, files, data-recovery, document-management

A friend of mine asked me to setup a home network which consists of a few computers and a printer as his employer had recently gone out of business. 2 of the laptops were brand new and 1 was his own which he used on the companies old network. I setup the 2 new laptops and setup network printing no problem.

However the other laptop which he used on the old company network was registed on their domain. I removed this computer from the domain by putting it into the default WORKGROUP the same as the other 2 laptops. However what I didn't know at the time was that his "My Documents" folder was set to redirect to the server. I attempted to retreive the files from the old user account with the local administrator account however I was unable to find the My Documents folder for this user. He was able to retrieve some of the files from the old server as they still currently have access to where they are saved, however some files are lost because he hasn't actually been on the old company network in over 2 weeks.

My question is: Does windows have a local cache of the My Documents folder when it is set to redirect? If so, how can I access it?

Laptop is running Windows XP, sever looks to be 2003.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joeqwerty points out, you may be out of luck if they are gone from the server and Offline Files was not configured.  Have you looked for the CSC folder that is used by Offline Files?  Usually c:\windows\CSC.  That is where the files are stored if Offline Files was configured.

Comment: just to follow up incase anyone else needs the info, the files in c:\windows\csc can be recovered using a tool called csccmd which you can get from a quick google

Answer (score 2):

There would only be a copy of the files on the workstation if My Documents Redirection was configured in conjunction with Offline Files. My Documents Redirection does exactly what it sounds like it does; it redirects the My Documents Folder, so no local copy would exist unless Offline Files were configured as well for the My Documents folder. It doesn't sound like that's the case here and my presumption is that the files that are missing are in fact gone if you're unable to find them on the server.